# Java RMI: Cannot rebind from a non-local host

Tags: registry, rmi, remote-access

I am working in a distributed application model where I have 3 applications running on 3 different machines (Say A,B and C). I would like machine A to be a dedicated RMI Registry host. Now I want an application running on B to register an RMI service on registry in A so that another application running on machine C to access this service through A.
As I understand now Java RMI registry does not allow binding from  a non-local host.
Is there any solution to achieve such remote communication among JVMs running across several machines?

Answer (score 0):

Use something other than a Registry: for example, an LDAP server.

Comment: I was googling through simultaneously and found something like 'Cajo'. Can you comment if it can solve this problem?

Comment: It definitely cannot solve this problem. It's just a thinnish layer *over* RMI. He asked me to review it when writing it. I could never see the point of it at all.